# Cut an AABB by an OBB

Tags: algorithm, 3d

I have two objects in a **3D** space:

- AABB (Axis Aligned Bounding Box) represented by two 3D points: min & max
- OBB (Orientated Bounding Box) represented by center position point, 3 half sizes and an orientation (quaternion for example)

I would like to 'cut' the parts of the AABB which exceeds the OBB. See attached image which represent an OBB and the AABB to cut to the red line:

[image: AABB cut by OBB]

I need to have a fast algorithm in order to do real time computation. Do you have any clues to construct a such algorithm ?

Comment: Crack open an old copy of one of Andrew Glassner's [Graphics Gems](http://www.graphicsgems.org/) series?